# display current time in android application on HTC wildfire

Tags: android, date-format, htc-android

I have created a basic app, which shows current timings using the following code

```
String currentime = dateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

It works perfect on the emulator eg. 10:25:00 AM, whereas in HTC wildfire it displays as 10:25:00 missing the AM/PM. could anybody help me on this.

Comment: I think you are getting date in 24 hr format.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a SimpleDateFormat object to convert the time formats.

```
 final String time = "23:15";

try {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
    final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println(dateObj);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(dateObj));
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

here is the javadoc [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for SimpleDateFromat.

Comment: Thanks Sam. But my problem is the time appears fine on emulator but not on the HTC wildfire. Is this could be due to format issue?

Comment: i have to check with code. its not possible but why possible i dnt know?